# SQL - How to select the products that have received the most like?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I have two table

```
Product(id, ..., other attribute...)
```

in relation with

```
UserLikeProduct(id, product_id, like_at, user_id)
```

How do I select the **Product** s that have received the most like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to build a result of user likes ordered from high to low

```
select product_id,count(*) as TotLikes
from UserLikeProduct
group by Product_id
```

Now join this with the product table

```
select p.Product_id,tl.TotLikes * 
from Products p
join *
(     select product_id,count(*) as TotLikes
    from UserLikeProduct
    group by Product_id

) tl on tl.Product_id=p.Product_id
order by 2 DESC
```